# How can I add firstName and lastName to fullName?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
person = { firstName: 'Joseph', lastName: 'Magnolia', ageInYears: 34 }

function addFullName(personObj) {
  person = { fullName: firstName + lastName, ageInYears: 34, }
}
```

It tells me `undefined`, and I have tried different things.

Comment: `firstName` and `lastName` are not defined anywhere. Did you mean `person.firstName` and `person.lastName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code doesn't really make any sense, but did you mean something like this:

```js
var person = { firstName: 'Joseph', lastName: 'Magnolia', ageInYears: 34 };
addFullName(person);
console.log(person);

function addFullName(personObj) {
      personObj.fullName = personObj.firstName + ' ' + personObj.lastName;
    }
```

Comment: for some reason it wasn't letting me input it how it normally would look, but yes thats what i was looking for. Took me a bit. Thanks!